# Trouble linking c++ exe against C library (GNU)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, g++

I've created some simple basic code to illustrate my problem.

header.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#   define API extern "C"
#else
#   define API
#endif

void callback();
API void libFunction();
```

testlib.c:

```
#include "header.h"

void libFunction()
{
    Callback();
}
```

I compile this as a static library like so:

```
gcc -c testlib.c
ar rsc libtest.a testlib.o
```

Then my sample c++ code is

main.cpp:

```
extern  "C"{
#include  <lib/header.h>
}
#include  <stdio.h>

main()
{
    libFunction();
}

void Callback()
{
    printf("Callback is called \n");
}
```

and I try to build my exe as so

```
g++ -I. -L. main.cpp -ltest
```

and get the following error

```
./lib/libtest.a(testlib.o): In function `libFunction':
testlib.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `Callback'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have spent literally all day trying to figure out why. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call `Callback` from a C file, it needs to be built `extern "C"` in your C++ file - otherwise C++ name mangling will cause the symbols to not line up.  You need to change the definition of `Callback()` in `main.cpp` to be:

```
extern "C" void Callback()
```

You have a case mismatch, too.  The prototype in your header says `callback`, but everywhere else you use `Callback`.  On re-reading your code, I think just fixing this case mismatch will solve all your problems.  I didn't see the `extern  "C"` wrapper around the `#include <lib/header.h>` on first reading.

Comment: Hi you're right about the case mismatch, that was the only problem with my posted code. I fixed it and it's compiling now, even without the extern.

Comment: Now I just need to find out why my much larger "real" code isn't linking lol, thanks for the reply

Comment: @BrandonYates - yeah, that makes sense.  I didn't notice the `extern "C"` wrapper you had around that `#include` statement in your `main.cpp` file.  You should be OK just fixing the case.